# 2D array literals in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, literals

I'm trying to construct a 2D array in the form of pointers-to-pointers. This doesn't work:

```
bool** data =  {
    new bool[4] {true, true, true, true},
    new bool[4] {true, false, false, true},
    new bool[4] {true, false, false, true},
    new bool[4] {true, true, true, true}
};
```

Is it possible? How should I be doing it?

---

#### EDIT:

Looks like I might be trying to do the wrong thing. I have a function that takes a 2D array of `bool`s of an unknown size, along with integer width and height, as arguments. At present, the signature is:

```
 foo(bool** data, int width, int height)
```

I want to be able to construct a literal for data, but I also need this function to work for any size of array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could have an array of arrays (sometimes referred to as a multi-dimensional array):

```
bool data[][4] =  {
    {true, true, true, true},
    {true, false, false, true},
    {true, false, false, true},
    {true, true, true, true}
};
```

However, that isn't convertible to `bool**`, so if you need that conversion then this won't work.

Alternatively, an array of pointers to static arrays (which *is* convertible to `bool**`):

```
bool data0 = {true, true, true, true};
bool data1 = {true, false, false, true};
bool data2 = {true, false, false, true};
bool data3 = {true, true, true, true};
bool * data[] = {data0, data1, data2, data3};
```

or if you really want dynamic arrays (which is almost certainly a bad idea):

```
bool * make_array(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    bool * array = new bool[4];
    array[0] = a;
    array[1] = b;
    array[2] = c;
    array[3] = d;
    return array;
}

bool * data[] = {
    make_array(true, true, true, true),
    make_array(true, false, false, true),
    make_array(true, false, false, true),
    make_array(true, true, true, true)
};
```

or, perhaps, you could stick with arrays, and modify your functions to take references to arrays rather than pointers, inferring the dimensions as template parameters if you need to support different dimensions. This is only possible if the dimensions are always known at compile time.

```
template <size_t N, size_t M>
void do_something(bool (&array)[N][M]);

do_something(data);
```

Comment: +1, Although I wouldn't call the first one an array of arrays, that's kind of ambiguous. It's more of a single array with special access syntax.

Comment: @NiklasB.: An array of arrays is exactly (and unambiguously) what it is. But the standard also refers to such a thing as a "multi-dimensional array", so I'll add that phrase as well.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up :) Always happy to learn new things.

Comment: Went for a template based overload that took an array of fixed size, and converted it to a pointer-to-pointer-to-bool. I'm surprised how clever the template is - I was expecting to have to do `do_something<2, 4>(twoByFourArray)` instead of `do_something(twoByFourArray)`.

Comment: One can also do an array of `[x * y]` where `array[i, j] = array[i * y + j]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
bool data_[][4] =  {
     {true, true, true, true},
     {true, false, false, true},
     {true, false, false, true},
     {true, true, true, true}
};
bool *data[4] = { data_[0], data_[1], data_[2], data_[3] };
```

Comment: I need it as a `bool**` to pass it into a function call that accepts any size of array

Comment: you can pass 'data' to such a function.

Comment: Firstly, that doesn't work for me without a bounds size in the second square brackets. Secondly, the compiler complains that _"no instance of overloaded function "f" matches the argument list"_ if I attempt to pass a `bool[][4]` where a `bool**` is expected.

Comment: @perreal: Depends on what input format the receiving function expects.

Comment: @Eric: Does the function expect an array of arrays or a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: @NiklasB: It takes a 2D array of unknown dimensions, as well as width and height arguments.

Comment: @perreal: No, you can't. An array is convertible to a pointer, but an array of arrays is not convertible to an array of pointers.

Comment: @Eric: Hm the spec sounds like it would actually receive something like this static, 2D array, but then why does it accept `bool**` instead of `bool*`? That API is strange, you should find out what exactly it expects as input (array of pointers or 2D array).

Comment: @perreal: What the hell? Now you are just forcing it to fit (which it probably doesnt...)

Comment: @Mike: g++ says it wants bool ** instead of bool (*)[2], so I thought casting is OK.

Comment: @perreal: `bool**` is something entirely different from `bool (*)[2]`. You can't sensibly cast one into the other.

Comment: @NiklasB: It's quite possible I've designed my API badly. See my edit.

Comment: @Eric: I added an answer how you might change that function signature to make it work with simple arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool *data[] =  {
    (bool []){true, true, true, true}
     ,(bool[]) {true, false, false, true}
     ,(bool[]) {true, false, false, true}
     ,(bool[]) {true, true, true, true}
};
```

This is convertible to `bool**` as you wish.  This is not an array of arrays.  This is an array of pointers.

By prefacing each row with `(bool [])` we enable it to decay to a pointer.  Each row is therefore a pointer, and can then be brought together into an array of four pointers.

Edit: You can drop the explicit `4` inside the `[`braces`]`, as it can be deduced by the compiler.

Comment: In `C++14`, this issues warning `warning: temporary whose address is used as value of member of local variable 'data' will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression`. See [here](https://cpp.sh/?source=%2F%2F+Example+program%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++std%3A%3Astring+name%3B%0A++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22What+is+your+name%3F+%22%3B%0A++getline+(std%3A%3Acin%2C+name)%3B%0A++std%3A%3Acout+%3C%3C+%22Hello%2C+%22+%3C%3C+name+%3C%3C+%22!%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D) (huh link doesn't work; see [this screenshot](https://ibb.co/Xt780XL))